# LTPA ChallengeHandler Javascript MFP8

Tags: javascript, ibm-mobilefirst, hybrid-mobile-app, ltpa

I'm working on the new Platform MFP8 and I want to implement an LTPA Authentication in an hybrid application. Searching in the web I found a Swift implementation of LTPA ChallengeHandler (https://github.com/mfpdev/ldap-and-ltpa-sample/tree/master/LTPABasedSample). But, if I try to replicate the same behaviour in a JS challengeHandler, it doesn't work.
Below my challengeHandler implementation:

```
var UserLoginChallengeHandler = function() {
    var isChallenged = false;
    var securityCheckName = 'LTPA';
    var URL;
    var userLoginChallengeHandler = WL.Client.createSecurityCheckChallengeHandler(securityCheckName);

    document.getElementById("login").addEventListener("click", login);

    userLoginChallengeHandler.securityCheckName = securityCheckName;

    userLoginChallengeHandler.handleChallenge = function(challenge) {
        WL.Logger.debug("handleChallenge");
        showLoginDiv();
        isChallenged = true;
        URL = challenge.loginURL;
    };

    userLoginChallengeHandler.handleSuccess = function(data) {
        WL.Logger.debug("handleSuccess");
        isChallenged = false;
        showProtectedDiv();
    };

    userLoginChallengeHandler.handleFailure = function(error) {
        WL.Logger.debug("handleFailure: " + error.failure);
        isChallenged = false;
        if (error.failure !== null){
            alert(error.failure);
        } else {
            alert("Failed to login.");
        }
    };

    function login() {

        var basic = "Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4="; //base64 of admin:admin 
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: URL,
          headers: {
            "Authorization": basic
          },
          success: function(data, status, xhr){
            console.log(data);
            userLoginChallengeHandler.submitChallengeAnswer({});
          },
          error: function(jqXhr, status, error){
            console.log(error);
          }
        });
    }

    return userLoginChallengeHandler;

};
```

When I submit the request for plain-war application, the principal in the authorize method of LTPASecurityCheck results null.
Instead, if I execute the iOS example application, the principal is valued and the authentication occurs.

Have you any idea to resolve this strange behavior?

Thanks a lot,
Stefano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the Swift sample is not sending POST request but GET. Have you tried to send it as GET?

Comment: I've tried but nothing is changed. The principal is still null

Comment: Could be that cookies not passed because of cross domain issue. Try to use WLResourceRequest if possible.. and not ajax. WLResourceRequest is invoke through native code so cookies will passed

Comment: To inspect if cookies is passed along to the server you can use Charles web proxy or Wireshark

Comment: Using WLResourceRequest it works like a charm! Thanks